# Java IE - internet explorer for java

Tags: java, internet-explorer, add-on

Do you know what can I use to open page in my application and to manage it using for example DOM

(when I want to change content of text area for example ?)

I'm talking here about something working which can for example support cookies etc. (Even addon)

Comment: It is called a web browser ... not an internet explorer.  "Internet Explorer" refers to a family of web browsers that run (only) on the Windows operating systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous Web browsers implemented in Java. For example:

- [Qt Jambi](http://qtjambi.sourceforge.net)
- [Lobo](http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp) (not maintained any more)
- [SWT Browser Widget](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-browser-widget/browser.html)
- [HotJava Browser](http://java.sun.com/products/archive/hotjava/) (not maintained any more)
- [NetBeans Embedded Browser](http://wiki.netbeans.org/EmbeddedBrowser)

Comment: I don't think Lobo is maintained anymore. Another option is Qt Jambi from Trolltech / nokia - although the api is a bit limited as many methods are final so can't be over-ridden. Also HotJava no longer maintained.